# ios open third party app within my own app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am new to ios.In my app we have documents like PDF,.DOC if we click that document means it will check wheather any third party app is installed in device or not.if any app installed (Ex.PDF Reader)the document is open that app.After opening the document suppose if user close the app i want to navigate to my APP

How to do that?

Comment: It's imposible to do that. You can not gain any control against other app.

Comment: thanks for you Update Orkenstein.So once the third party is opened shall we show one button Like that so we navigate to our app.Is it possible?

Comment: In your app or 3rd party app?

Comment: No, you can't. Honestly, you don't need.
Read about `UIActivityController`  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/

Comment: if i open the PPT in DocumentInteraction Controller it opened but the animation in PPT is not working and alignment is changed

Comment: You better start a separate question then.

Comment: i already posted seperate question but no answer

PPT alignment is changed while present the document in DocumentInteractionController?

Answer (score 0):

You could use apples PDF Kit and open the pdf within your own app that should give you the control you want.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH203-SW1